# User form to edit existing data and add new entries

Tags: excel, vba, userform, data-entry

I have a sheet that contains a list of accounts and their various asset allocations. Their account numbers are non sequential and are kept in Column A. Currently I have code (see below) that allows users to search the existing data and adjust the asset allocations using [this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sjGC.jpg).

I am hoping to use this same form to allow users to also add new accounts.

In essence I need the form to check if the number entered into the Account Number field already exists and update the allocations associated or, if the account number doesn’t exist, to add that account number to the last empty row of column A and fill out the associated allocations as inputted in the other fields.

This seems straight forward enough when written down but I can’t wrap my head around how to do it.

Please see existing code below

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()
If Me.AccSearch.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter an account number", vbExclamation, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim AccNo As Long
Dim AccFound As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Register")
AccNo = Me.AccSearch.Value

With Range("A:A")
Set AccFound = .Find(AccNo)

With AccFound
.Offset(0, 22) = Me.AusMin.Value
.Offset(0, 23) = Me.AusMax.Value
.Offset(0, 24) = Me.IntMin.Value
.Offset(0, 25) = Me.IntMax.Value
.Offset(0, 40) = Me.PrpMin.Value
.Offset(0, 41) = Me.PrpMax.Value
.Offset(0, 42) = Me.FixMin.Value
.Offset(0, 43) = Me.FixMax.Value
.Offset(0, 34) = Me.AltMin.Value
.Offset(0, 44) = Me.AltMin.Value
.Offset(0, 35) = Me.AltMax.Value
.Offset(0, 45) = Me.AltMax.Value
.Offset(0, 36) = Me.CashMin.Value
.Offset(0, 46) = Me.CashMin.Value
.Offset(0, 37) = Me.CashMax.Value
.Offset(0, 47) = Me.CashMax.Value
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. You will need to try yourself and ask a question when you run into a problem with the code.

Comment: Try, after `Set AccFound = .Find(AccNo)`, insert a line `if AccFound is nothing then set AccFound = range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).offset(1,0)` ---> this will give AccFound range to a blank cell right after the last row with data in column A. Next line is your code `With AccFound` and so on. Not tested in my side.